# Question related to infinitely generated ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, integral-domain

Let $A$ be a domain and $X \subset A$. Then
$(X) = \{a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n \mid 
n \in \mathbb{N},\, a_i \in A,\, x_i \in X\}$

What I understand from the above theorem is that if $x\in X$ then there is a way to express it as a linear combination of a finite number of elements of $X$. If $X$ were an infinite set, whose elements are $x_i$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$, then there exists an element of $(X)$ that can be expressed as a sum of infinite quantity of $x_i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the linear combination must be finite. Infinite sums might not even be defined.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering. Perhaps this question is obvious: the sum must be finite by "definition" since the infinite sum is not defined? In any case, is there any algebraic structure where the infinite sum can be defined?

Comment: Yes, the infinite sum isn't always defined. For example, $1 + 1 + 1 + ...$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. In some cases (such as a normed vector space), there are convergent infinite series which is one way to define some (but not all) infinite sums.